# Java Thread.sleep()

Tags: java

I am making a server and client pair and I wanted a time interval between the times that it sends the server data. Does `Thread.sleep();` serve for that purpose? I tried that before on a previous project and the entire application froze for the amount of milliseconds, which is not what I wanted. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try creating a separate thread for sending data and calling thread.sleep only on that one.

Comment: If you sleep on the main GUI dispatch thread then yes, the entire app will freeze.  If the code that sends data to the server runs on its own thread then you could use `sleep()` to pace the sending. Your question isn't detailed enough for anybody to help.

Comment: What type of application? Did it use `Swing` by any chance?

Comment: Have you considered reading the Javadoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread will be suspended ("freeze") for that duration (or until interrupted). If your app is multi-threaded, other threads will continue to run. Separate your communications thread from your UI thread (or whatever else you don't want delayed by this communications wait) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes", `Thread.sleep` could be used for this task.

You could also use:

- `java.util.Timer`
- `SwingWorker`

Which might be more suitable solutions, depending on your needs.

`Thread.sleep` freezing your application denotes that you call it from within the context of your application's main thread.  If this a GUI, especially based on Swing, this suggests that you are calling it from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

In either case, I would suggest using a separate `Thread` or `java.util.Timer` or if your using a Swing UI, `SwingWorker`.

Take a look at:

- [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

For more ideas